# C pointer in append function is not updating value for head and tail

Tags: c, linked-list

Created a function that takes a List Struct pointer and a double value that is the data that is going to be stored in the linked list.  When I call the function to add values they are being stored as both the head and the tail and previous values are not being saved.

The list struct:

```
typedef struct LIST_{
    int size;

    int (*match)(const void *key1, const void *key2);
    void (*destroy)(void *data);

    ListElmt *head;
    ListElmt *tail;
}List;
```

The list_init function:

```
void list_init(List *pPolynomial, void (*destroy)(void *data)){
    pPolynomial->size = 0;
    pPolynomial->destroy = destroy;
    pPolynomial->head = NULL;
    pPolynomial->tail = NULL;

}
```

The append term function:

```
List* appendTerm(List *pPolynomial, double constant){
//inserting value at the end of the list
    ListElmt *element;
    element = (ListElmt *)malloc(sizeof(ListElmt));
    double* d = &constant;
    element->data = d;

    if(pPolynomial->size == 0){
        //if there was no head
        pPolynomial->head = element;
        pPolynomial->tail = element;
        element->next = NULL;
        printf("This is the data stored in the head %f \n", *(double*)pPolynomial->head->data);
        printf("This is the data stored in the tail %f \n", *(double*)pPolynomial->tail->data);
    }
    else{
        //there is a head
        pPolynomial->tail = pPolynomial->tail->next;
        pPolynomial->tail->next = element;

        element->next = NULL;
        printf("else statement: This is the data still stored in the head %f \n", *(double*)pPolynomial->head->data);
        printf("This is the data stored in the tail %f \n", *(double*)pPolynomial->tail->data);
    }
    pPolynomial->size++;
    printf("size: %d\n", pPolynomial->size);

    return pPolynomial;
}



int main() {
    List* listOfInts;
    ListElmt *pElmt;
    double *pDbl;
    int i;


    list_init(listOfInts, free);
    listOfInts = appendTerm(listOfInts, 5);
    listOfInts = appendTerm(listOfInts,6);
    listOfInts = appendTerm(listOfInts,7);

    pElmt = listOfInts->head;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        double d = *(double *) pElmt->data;
        printf("List elem %d = %f\n", i, d);
        pElmt = pElmt->next;
     }


    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This is the output of the program:

```
This is the data stored in the head 5.000000 
This is the data stored in the tail 5.000000 
size: 1
else statement: This is the data still stored in the head 6.000000 
This is the data stored in the tail 6.000000 
size: 2
else statement: This is the data still stored in the head 7.000000 
This is the data stored in the tail 7.000000 
size: 3
List elem 0 = 7.000000
List elem 1 = 0.000000
List elem 2 = 0.000000
```

Comment: Show the definition of `list_init` and `List`. Are you storing a double or a pointer do a double

Comment: @Inian I think he might be storing a pointer to `void` since he's casting.

Comment: Just added the definition of list_init and List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to store a pointer to a double in your list.  Just store the double.  The problem with storing a pointer is managing it.  In your case, you store a *pointer to a local variable* within your struct:

```
double* d = &constant;
element->data = d;
```

Once the `appendTerm` function returns, the variable this pointer points to has gone out of scope, and the pointer is dangling, resulting in Undefined Behavior when you dereference it.

This end result of this (in your test) is that all of the nodes point at the same memory location, which (at the time you print the list contents) still holds the last value stored in the list.

The solution is to store the double within `ListElmt` rather than a pointer.  If you have to store a pointer, you'll need to `malloc` the space to hold it (and free that space when getting rid of the node).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  How can I store a double to the ListElmt in the function when data is a type void*. And didn't I malloc a ListElmt so it should have the space to hold the constant.  Sorry I'm a little new to C programming so have all of these questions

Comment: You can store a double by changing the type of data to `double data`.  If you need to leave it a pointer, you'll need to use `element->data = malloc(sizeof(double)); *element->data = d;` (but you'll want to add error checking in between those two statements to make sure the `malloc` succeeded).

Answer (score 2):

below two lines need to be swapped.

```
pPolynomial->tail->next = element;
pPolynomial->tail = pPolynomial->tail->next;
```

because `pPolynomial->tail->next` is over written before it is assigned to tail.